# Error using Numpy in Netbeans 8

Tags: python, numpy, netbeans

I´m trying to use Numpy but after 2 or 3 days googleing it´s not working.
When I want to import numpy I have the following error:

```
"ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there."
```

I don´t know how to change my working directory or what do I have to do...

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you

Comment: How and where did you import numpy? Can you post the code?

Comment: I was importing it in Netbeans but I have installed "Anaconda" and now everything is working fine.